# How to setState does work in my flutter code?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-state

https://github.com/kangsudal/performance_tracker/blob/main/lib/main.dart

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String str_addUpToFirst = '''
    int addUpToFirst(n) {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        total += i;
      }
      return total;
    }
    ''';
    int addUpToFirst(n) {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        total += i;
      }
      return total;
    }
    Duration duration = Duration(microseconds: 0);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text("Performance Tracker"),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {

                          setState(() {
                            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
                            addUpToFirst(10000000);
                            duration = stopwatch.elapsed;
                          });
                          print(
                              'addUpToFirst() executed in ${duration}');
                        },
                        child: Text("addUpToFirst"),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text("addUpToSecond"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                          width: 50,
                          child: TextField()),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('Plot!'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              // color: Colors.black,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          child: LayoutBuilder(
                            builder: (context, constraints) {
                              return Container(
                                color: Colors.yellow[100],
                                width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.9,
                                height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.5,
                                child: Text(str_addUpToFirst),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Text('$duration'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            flex: 2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

In onpressed(), print works.
"addUpToFirst() executed in 0:00:00.047199"
I expected duration value should be changed to 0:00:00.047199. in layout. but it isn't. still 0.
I don't know why setState change duration value in layout.
I need help. Thank you.

Comment: **I don't know why setState doesn't change duration value in layout.

Comment: I don't see the code that is referencing duration to put it into a widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using any `state` variable.

In a `StatefulWidget` you usually have some class properties (or variables), whereas you're declaring everything inside your `build` method. [Here](https://github.com/kangsudal/performance_tracker/blob/7a6aa1b46d9d9cdb11a92aa94a2e71b6e5139296/lib/main.dart#L45)'s the problem. You should move that variable outside the `build` method and make it a class property.

You always had `0` in your layout because, even though you correctly invoke and use `setState` to update `duration`, every time `setState` is called, by definition the `build` method is re-run and therefore you re-initialize `duration` to zero *in the next rebuild*.

This is why the `print` statement worked (it's in the button callback and executes in its own scope) while the layout didn't.

Code (I didn't test it):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var duration = Duration(microseconds: 0);  // This is the only change!
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String str_addUpToFirst = '''
    int addUpToFirst(n) {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        total += i;
      }
      return total;
    }
    ''';
    int addUpToFirst(n) {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        total += i;
      }
      return total;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text("Performance Tracker"),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
                            addUpToFirst(10000000);
                            duration = stopwatch.elapsed;
                          });
                          print('addUpToFirst() executed in ${duration}');
                        },
                        child: Text("addUpToFirst"),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text("addUpToSecond"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                          width: 50,
                          child: TextField()),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('Plot!'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              // color: Colors.black,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          child: LayoutBuilder(
                            builder: (context, constraints) {
                              return Container(
                                color: Colors.yellow[100],
                                width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.9,
                                height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.5,
                                child: Text(str_addUpToFirst),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Text('$duration'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            flex: 2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call the setState method, the build method is called again.
So the value that needs to be changed remains the same.

> So instead of declaring variables inside the build method, you need to
> call variables outside the build method.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Duration duration = const Duration(microseconds: 0);

  String str_addUpToFirst = '''
    int addUpToFirst(n) {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        total += i;
      }
      return total;
    }
    ''';
  int addUpToFirst(n) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      total += i;
    }
    return total;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text("Performance Tracker"),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
                            addUpToFirst(10000000);
                            duration = stopwatch.elapsed;
                          });
                          print('addUpToFirst() executed in ${duration}');
                        },
                        child: const Text("addUpToFirst"),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text("addUpToSecond"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
                          width: 50,
                          child: const TextField()),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text('Plot!'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              // color: Colors.black,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          child: LayoutBuilder(
                            builder: (context, constraints) {
                              return Container(
                                color: Colors.yellow[100],
                                width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.9,
                                height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.5,
                                child: Text(str_addUpToFirst),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Text('$duration'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            flex: 2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'Duration duration = Duration(microseconds: 0)'is declared in Widget build, when you setstate, rebuild ui in build and assign the value of the variable to 0 again.
You should put duration outside 'Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}'.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html